# SQL - Count and group records by month and field value from the last year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, count, group-by

I need to count totals number of records in a table, 'a', where a field in 'a', say 'type', has a certain value, 'v'. From all these records where a.type = 'v', I need to group these twice: first by field 'b_id', and again by month. The date range for these records must be restricted to the last year *from the current date*

I already have the totals for the 'b_id' field with ISNULL() as follows:

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM a
    WHERE a.type = 'v'
    AND b.b_id = a.b_id
), 0) AS b_totals
```

The data lies in table a, and is joined on table b. 'b_id' is the primary key for table b, and is found in table a (thought it is not part of a's key). The key for a is irrelevant to the data I need to pull, but can be stated as "a_id" for simplicity.

How do I:

- Restrict these records to the past twelve months from the current date.
- Take the total for any and all values of b.id, and categorize them by month. This is in addition to the totals of b.id by year. The date is stored in field "date_occurred" in table 'a' as a standard date/time type.

The schema at the end should look something like this, assuming that the current month is October and the year is 2016:

```
b.id | b_totals | Nov. 2015 | Dec. 2015 | Jan. 2016 .... Oct. 2016
__________________________________________________________________
ID_1      1           0         0           0               1
ID_2      3           2         0           1               0
ID_3      5           1         1           3               0
```

EDIT: I should probably clarify that I'm counting the records in table 'a' where field 'f' has a certain value 'v.' From these records, I need to group them by building then by month/date. I updated my ISNULL query to make this more clear, as well as the keys for a and b. "date_occured" should be in table a, not b, that was a mistake/typo on my end.

If it helps, the best way I can describe the data from a high level without giving away any sensitive data:

- 'b' is a table of locations, and 'b.b_id' is the ID for each location
- 'a' is a table of events. The location for these events is found in 'a.b_id' and joined on 'b.b_id' The date that each event occured is in 'a.date_occurred'
- I need to restrict the type of events to a certain value. In this case, the type is field 'type.' This is the "where" clause in my ISNULL SQL query that gets the totals by location.
- From all the events of this particular type, I need to count how many times this event occurred in the past year for each location. Once I have these totals from the past year, I need to count them by month.

Table structure:
The table structure of a is something like

a.a_id | a.b_id | a.type | a.date_occurred

Again, I do not need the ID's from a: just a series of counts based on type, b_id, and date_occurred.

EDIT 2: I restricted the totals of b_id to the past year with the following query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM a
    WHERE a.type = 'v'
    AND b.b_id = a.b_id
    AND a.date_occurred BETWEEN (DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE()) AND (GETDATE())
), 0) AS b_totals
```

Now need to do this with a PIVOT and the months.

Comment: Without knowing the table structure, it's not really possible to give you an actual query, but you're going to need to use dynamic SQL to generate the column names, and the general idea behind your query will be a pivot (based on the month of whatever the data you're looking at is).

Comment: I do hope you return to this question.... I have tried to interpret your words but you should consider these:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org both will help you prepare most precise questions and that will help you get solutions faster

Comment: I clarified some of the fields and values I was using, and fixed a typo: "date_occurred" should be in table a, not b. The only purpose of table b is to join the field where "id" (which I updated to "b_id" to make clear") comes from. I also gave a high-level overview of what needs to be done. If you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask, but I am bound somewhat due to company/client confidentiality. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Used_By_Already hope this helps...

Comment: did you read about MCVE or SSCCE ? if you want a question answered  quickly and precisely then there is a recipe to achieve that. 1. "sample data" and 2. "expected result". Provide the data we need to produce the conditions that are to be solved, and (from the data supplied) present the expected result (yes you do this manually). We can then work on the middle bit (how to get from data to result). I can't do any more than I already have without data and a result that can be derived from that data.

Comment: Also; how much effort should I devote to writing your code for you (when there is not much visible effort from you)? Have you attempted to apply anything I outlined below? (which is already a lot of effort don't you think?)

Comment: @Used_By_Already TBH I haven't worked with SQL on this complex of a scale before, so I thought adding some more clarification would yield a simpler solution (ultimately this is going in as a custom SQL statement into an API/XML file, and I'm not so sure it's friendly with the SQL variables and execute statement, save the fact I haven't used either before). I assumed that I didn't need to supply any data considering that these are just counts and I gave an example of what the end result should look like and the schema for table a. Nonetheless, I really do appreciate your detailed solution.

Comment: And I  have demonstrated exactly what you need to do using a and b with my example data. It is much easier for you to comprehend if you supply the data. if you are unable to apply this to your circumstances you would be advised to use the real table names and real column names and your own relevant data plus be exact about the expected results. truly adding more words in the question isn't adding value. I see nothing in the added words for me to simplify the solution. The cause of the complexity is the columns with monthyear as headings. that requires dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to make this sufficiently detailed from the absolute minimum of detail provided in the question I have created these 2 example tables with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE Bexample
    ([ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Bexample
    ([ID])
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6),
    (7),
    (8),
    (9)
;


CREATE TABLE Aexample
    ([ID] int, [B_PK] int, [SOME_DT] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Aexample
    ([ID], [B_PK], [SOME_DT])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 3, '2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
    (4, 4, '2015-04-01 00:00:00'),
    (5, 5, '2015-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (6, 6, '2015-06-01 00:00:00'),
    (7, 7, '2015-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (8, 8, '2015-08-01 00:00:00'),
    (9, 9, '2015-09-01 00:00:00'),
    (10, 1, '2015-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (11, 2, '2015-11-01 00:00:00'),
    (12, 3, '2015-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (13, 1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (14, 2, '2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (15, 3, '2016-03-01 00:00:00'),
    (16, 4, '2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
    (17, 5, '2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (18, 6, '2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
    (19, 7, '2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (20, 8, '2016-08-01 00:00:00'),
    (21, 9, '2016-09-01 00:00:00'),
    (22, 1, '2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (23, 2, '2016-11-01 00:00:00'),
    (24, 3, '2016-12-01 00:00:00')
;
```

Now, using those tables and data I can generate a result table like this:

```
id  Nov 2015  Dec 2015  Jan 2016  Feb 2016  Mar 2016 Apr 2016 May 2016 Jun 2016 Jul 2016 Aug 2016 Sep 2016 Oct 2016
1        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1
2        1        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
3        0        1        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
4        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
5        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
6        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
7        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0
8        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0
9        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
```

Using a query that needs both a "common table expression (CTE) and "dynamic sql" to produce that result:

"Dynamic SQL" is a query that generates SQL which is then executed. This is needed because the column names change month to month. So, for the dynamic sql we declare 2 variables that will hold the generated SQL. One of these is to store the columns names, which gets used in 2 places, and the other is to hold the completed query. Note instead of executing this you may display the generated SQL as you evelop your solution (note the comments near execute at the end of the query).

In addition to the example tables and data, we also have a "time series" of 12 months to consider. This is "dynamic" as it is calculated from today's date and I have assumed that if today is any day within November 2016, that "the last 12 months" starts at 1 Nov 2015, and concludes at 31 Oct 2016 (i.e. 12 full months, no partial months).

The core of calculating this is here:

```
DATEADD(month,-12, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()), 0) )
```

which firstly locates the first day of the current month with `DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE())` then deducts a further 12 months from that date. With that as a start date a "recursive CTE" is used to generate 12 rows, one for each month for the past 12 full months.

The purpose of these 12 rows is to ensure that when we consider the actual table data there will be no gaps in the 12 columns. This is achieved by using the generated 12 rows as the "from table" in our query, and the "A" table is LEFT JOINED based on the year/month of a date column [some_dt] to the 12 monthly rows.

So, we generate 12 rows join the sample data to these which is used to generate the SQL necessary for a "PIVOT" of the data. Here it is useful to actually see that an `example of that generated sql`, which looks like this:

```
SELECT id, [Nov 2015],[Dec 2015],[Jan 2016],[Feb 2016],[Mar 2016],[Apr 2016],[May 2016],[Jun 2016],[Jul 2016],[Aug 2016],[Sep 2016],[Oct 2016] FROM
                (
                    select
                          format([mnth],'MMM yyyy') colname
                        , b.id
                        , a.b_pk
                    from #mylist
                    cross join bexample b
                    left join aexample a on #mylist.mnth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,a.some_dt), 0)
                               and b.id = a.b_pk
               ) sourcedata
                pivot
                (
                    count([b_pk])
                    FOR [colname] IN ([Nov 2015],[Dec 2015],[Jan 2016],[Feb 2016],[Mar 2016],[Apr 2016],[May 2016],[Jun 2016],[Jul 2016],[Aug 2016],[Sep 2016],[Oct 2016])
                ) p
```

So, hopefully you can see in that generated SQL code that the dynamically created 12 rows become 12 columns. Note that because we are executing "dynamic sql" the 12 rows we generated as a CTE need to be stored as a "temporary table" (#mylist).

The query to generate AND execute that SQL is this.

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

;with mylist as (
      select DATEADD(month,-12, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()), 0) ) as [mnth]
      union all 
      select DATEADD(month,1,[mnth]) 
      from mylist
      where [mnth] < DATEADD(month,-1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()), 0) )
      )
select [mnth]
into #mylist
from mylist


    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(format([mnth],'MMM yyyy'))
                      FROM #mylist
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                      ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                  ,1,1,'')

    SET @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' FROM
                (
                    select
                          format([mnth],''MMM yyyy'') colname
                        , b.id
                        , a.b_pk
                    from #mylist
                    cross join bexample b
                    left join aexample a on #mylist.mnth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,a.some_dt), 0)
                               and b.id = a.b_pk
               ) sourcedata
                pivot
                (
                    count([b_pk])
                    FOR [colname] IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

--select @query -- use select to inspect the generated sql
execute(@query) -- once satisfied that sql is OK, use execute

drop table #mylist
```

You can see this working at: http://rextester.com/VVGZ39193

Answer (score 0):

I want to share another attempt at explaining the issues faced by your requirements.

To follow this you MUST understand this sample data. I have 2 tables @events (a) and @locations (b). The column names should be easy to follow I hope. The

```
declare @Events table
    (  [id] int IDENTITY(1007,2)
     , [b_id] int
     , [date_occurred] datetime
     , [type] varchar(20)
    )
;
    
INSERT INTO @Events
    ([b_id], [date_occurred],[type])
VALUES
    (1, '2015-01-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (2, '2015-02-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (3, '2015-03-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (4, '2015-04-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (5, '2015-05-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (6, '2015-06-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (1, '2015-07-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (2, '2015-08-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (3, '2015-09-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (5, '2015-10-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (5, '2015-11-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (6, '2015-12-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (1, '2016-01-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (2, '2016-02-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (3, '2016-03-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (4, '2016-04-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (5, '2016-05-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (6, '2016-06-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (1, '2016-07-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (2, '2016-08-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (3, '2016-09-21 00:00:00','v'),
    (4, '2016-10-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (5, '2016-11-11 00:00:00','v'),
    (6, '2016-12-11 00:00:00','v');


declare @Locations table
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(13))
;
    
INSERT INTO @Locations
    ([id], [name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Atlantic City'),
    (2, 'Boston'),
    (3, 'Chicago'),
    (4, 'Denver'),
    (5, 'Edgbaston'),
    (6, 'Melbourne')
;
```

OK. So with that data we can easily create a set of counts using this query:

```
select
      b.id
    , b.name
    , format(a.date_occurred,'yyyy MMM') mnth
    , count(*)
FROM @events a 
inner join @locations b ON b.id = a.b_id
WHERE a.type = 'v'
and a.date_occurred >= DATEADD(month,-12, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()), 0) )
group by
      b.id
    , b.name
    , format(a.date_occurred,'yyyy MMM')
```

And that output looks like this:

```
id name          mnth       
-- ------------- -------- - 
1  Atlantic City 2016 Jan 1 
1  Atlantic City 2016 Jul 1 
2  Boston        2016 Aug 1 
2  Boston        2016 Feb 1 
3  Chicago       2016 Mar 1 
3  Chicago       2016 Sep 1 
4  Denver        2016 Apr 1 
4  Denver        2016 Oct 1 
5  Edgbaston     2015 Nov 1 
5  Edgbaston     2016 May 1 
5  Edgbaston     2016 Nov 1 
6  Melbourne     2015 Dec 1 
6  Melbourne     2016 Dec 1 
6  Melbourne     2016 Jun 1
```

So, with a "simple" query that is easy to pass parameters into, the output is BY ROWS

and the column headings are FIXED

NOW do you understand why transposing those rows into columns, with VARIABLE COLUMN HEADING forces the use of dynamic sql?

Your requirements, no matter how many words you throw at it, leads to complexity in the sql.

You can run the above data/query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/574718/count-and-group-records-by-month-and-field-value-from-the-last-year